# Plotting netCDF data with Python: How to change grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm an new one in python and plotting data with Matplotlib. I really need help and thank you in advance for the answers.

So, I have a netCDF file with v-component of wind data. Grid coordinates: points=9600 (240x40)

lon : 0 to 358.5 by 1.5 degrees_east  circular

lat : 88.5 to 30 by -1.5 degrees_north

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

#read data from NETcdf file ".nc"
my_file = '/home/Era-Interim/NH-EraInt-1979.nc'
fh = Dataset(my_file, mode='r')

lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
V = fh.variables['V'][:]
V_units = fh.variables['V'].units

fh.close()

# create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

# create a map
m = Basemap(projection='nplaea',boundinglat=30,lon_0=10,resolution='l',round=True)

#draw parallels, meridians, coastlines, countries, mapboundary
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
#m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=2)

m.drawparallels(np.arange(30,90,20), labels=[1,1,0,0])  #paral in 10 degree, right, left 
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30), labels=[1,1,1,1])  #merid in 10 degree, bottom

#Plot the data on top of the map
lon,lat = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
x,y = m(lon,lat)

cs = m.pcolor(x,y,np.squeeze(V),cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r)

plt.title("", fontsize=25, verticalalignment='baseline')
plt.savefig("/home/Era-Interim/1.png")
```

As a result, I received a map (you can find in my dropbox folder) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nvy8wcodk9jtat0/AAC-omkPP8_7uINSSXbzImeja?dl=0

On the map, there are white pixels between 358.5 and 0 (360) lon, because I have no data between 358.5 and 0 (360) lon.

**The question is: how can I change the size of the grid, regrid it, interpolate data, or something else in order to not have this white sector?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. At the beginning of the script, you must add

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic
```

and further

```
datain, lonsin = addcyclic(np.squeeze(Q), lons)
lons, Q = m.shiftdata(lonsin, datain = np.squeeze(Q), lon_0=180.)
print lons
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x,y = m(lon, lat)
cs = m.pcolor(x,y,datain,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r)
```

The difference can be seen in the figures (I still can not post images).
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nvy8wcodk9jtat0/AAC-omkPP8_7uINSSXbzImeja?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case some kind of interpolation techniques can be applied.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510663/python-interpolation-with-matplotlib-basemap) out. There was similar problem.

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is 360 degrees is 0 degrees, so you can copy the 0 degrees data and it should look right. I may be interpreting this wrong though, as I believe that the data is representing the pressure levels at each of the points, not between the two points (i.e. at zero degrees, not between zero degrees and 1.5 degrees).

My interpretation means that, yes, you don't have data between 358.5 and 0, but you also don't have data between 357 and 358.5. This seems more likely than just skipping an area. This would mean that the data from 358.5 should be touching the data from 0 as it is just as far away as 0 is from 1.5 which is touching.

Copying the last bit would grant you the ability to change your m.pcolor call to an [imshow](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) call (as in [Roman Dryndik's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510663/python-interpolation-with-matplotlib-basemap)) and use interpolation to smooth out the graph.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. But I want to create a script that is suitable for visualization of large numbers of files with the same structure without spending time on formatting the files themselves. I have already found a solution.
Thank you very much for the answer!